# Cannot read property 'notificationsHub' of undefined? SignalR with angularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

> // angular controller

```
$scope.notification = $.connection.notificationsHub;

$scope.SendNotification = function (schoolId) {
    $http({
        url: "/Notifications/InsertNotification?SchoolId=" + schoolId+"&Notification="+$scope.Notification,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);


    notification.client.sendNotification = function () {
        getAllNotifications();
    }
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getAllNotifications();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert(e);
    })

    function getAllNotifications() {
        $http({
            url: "/Notifications/Notifications?SchoolId=" + schoolId,
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);

        });
    }
    });
}
```

> C# Code (hub class)

```
public void Send()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.SendNotification();
}
```

I tried to add map in owin startup class and all the scripts are placed just in the right place and I tried so many solutions and it doesn't work I need help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution says to comment or delete bundle register from global.cs file and it appears that the file of signalR have a conflict with other .js file in the bundleconfig.cs file and it solved